# how to change text color in eclipse Moonrise UI Theme when editing rpm

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rpm

I have installed the Moonrise UI Theme in eclipse but when I am trying to edit spec file (with the rpm eclipse plugin) I hardly can see the text. The fonts are black as the background. How can I change the font color ?